unable to open frida
I have ubuntu16.04 and i don't want to update it. python2.7 and 3.5 is installed on my ubuntu. i followed step
pip install frida
pip install frida frida-tools
it install in my 3.5 python now when i run frida it is giving me error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dilawer/.local/bin/frida", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/dilawer/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/frida_tools/repl.py", line 38, in main
    from frida_tools.cli_formatting import format_compiling, format_compiled, format_diagnostic
  File "/home/dilawer/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/frida_tools/cli_formatting.py", line 24
    return f"{STYLE_RESET_ALL}Compiling {STYLE_FILE}{name}{STYLE_RESET_ALL}..."
                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

when i use python --version on ubuntu it will give me 2.7 version response and when i view python3 --version response will be 3.5.2
frida 15.2.2 version is installed
Kindly let me know how can i fix this
Thanks

Usually if you have python 2 and 3 installed I remember that you should use pip3 to select Python 3. Standard pip will use Python 2.

The error message SyntaxError: invalid syntax refers to the code line return f"{STYLE_RESET_ALL}Compiling {STYLE_FILE}{name}{STYLE_RESET_ALL}..."
The main problem seems to be that it is a so-called "f-string" as it is written f"...".
These Python "f-strings" have been introduced in Python 3.6 with pep-0498 so you need at least that version.
Alternatively you can try to get an older version of frda-tools and a matching frida version. The file cli_formatting.pywhich causes the problem was introduced in September 2022 so you need a frida-tools version 11.0.0 or older (frida-tools v11.0.0 should work with frida 15.2.2).
